# Github pull request excluding some commits

Tags: git, github

I currently have two commits in my forked repository, and would like to exclude the latest commit when making a pull request to the original repository.

Is there a way to do this without discarding the latest commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Create a branch from the first commit, and create a pull-request from that branch:

```
git branch somebranchname HEAD~1
git push origin somebranchname:somebranchname
```

Comment: Creating a new branch! didn't think of that. Thank you.